Node.js Version Upgrade Issue with CoffeeScript Project
I am working on a project currently running on Node v6.11.4. I am trying to upgrade the Node version to v22.3.0 (latest). However, I am encountering several errors during the installation of Node modules.
Project details:
Developed using CoffeeScript
Uses MongoDB
Issue:
When running npm install, I receive the following error message:
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  package: 'pkgcloud@0.8.17',
  required: { node: '0.8.x || 0.10.x' },
  current: { node: 'v22.3.0', npm: '10.8.1' }
}
...
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /path/to/project/node_modules/contextify
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
...
../src/contextify.cc:52:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction()’

It appears that there are compatibility issues between the project's dependencies and the new Node.js version.
Steps I've taken:
Verified Node and NPM versions.
Attempted to update project dependencies using npm-check-updates.
Tried manually fixing dependency versions in package.json.
Despite these efforts, the errors persist.
Questions:
How can I resolve these compatibility issues?
Are there specific strategies for upgrading a project from Node v6 to v22, especially one using CoffeeScript and MongoDB?
Should I consider refactoring parts of the project to better support the newer Node version?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
